# How to write cross-platform C library and link it with iOS app?

Tags: c, ios, cross-platform

I need a lib to do some kind of caching. It must be cross-platform for reuse on Linux/Windows/iOS. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you want to cache? strings? numbers? blobs? HTTP responses? Function-call return values? ...?

Comment: You need to be more specific - what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I want to cache map tiles, which in fact are .png/.jpeg files, to the file system. So, the lib must implement put/get tile in a cross-platform manner and it should be available for iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, you need to put platform specific code inside #ifdef to only allow certain code to be compiled on different platforms.  It might be easier to create one common C library that will be the same across platforms and then three separate C libraries that handle platform specific code.

I think the code would be easier to read and manage this way.